# how do add multi sql dependency to this code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb-.net-driver

i have **person** table in sql server **with fields id and Name**

and csharp statement that work well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SQLNotifications
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        string connectionstring = @"Server=EEPERSIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Chatter;User ID=sa;pwd=1";

        delegate void GridDelegate(DataTable table);

        SqlDependency dep;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionstring);

            UpdateGrid();
        }

        private void UpdateGrid()
        {
            string sql = "select Name from dbo.person";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))

            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);

                    dep.OnChange += dep_OnChange;

                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dt.Load(rdr);
                    }
                }
            }

            dataGridView1.Invoke(
                (GridDelegate)delegate(DataTable table)
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = table; 
                }
                , dt);
        }
        private void dep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Insert Accourd");
            UpdateGrid();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDependency.Stop(connectionstring);
        }
    }
}
```

now , i have 2 problem :

**1- i cant understant this section of code**

```
 dataGridView1.Invoke(
                (GridDelegate)delegate(DataTable table)
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = table; 
                }
                , dt);
```

**2- i want monitor multi table instead of one table .** 
**How i can do this ?**

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: There is a bit of pseudo code in my sql answer, but I'd need more information on what  you mean by "monitor multi table", to give more.  is this what you're looking for?

Comment: my database have over 50 tables ___ i want do action based on favorite table when they changed (Most of the time after insert into table) ___  How Do i ? Plesae help ___ thanks

Comment: Let me know if my latest edit helped by upvoting and marking as answer. Or if there is anything that wasnt clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A delegate is just a method that doesnt return anything.  This code is just a call to an inline method.

Think of it like this:

```
 MyDelegateFunction(dt);

 private void MyDelegateFunction(DataTable table)
 {
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table; 
 }
```

`dt` is the parameter passed into the method, it is set to the datasource of the `dataGridView`

Here is the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.110).aspx) article for that method.

2 - If by monitoring many tables you mean you want to see the data from them, then you just change the sql that you are using to query.

This:

```
string sql = "select Name from dbo.person";
```

Might change to this:

```
string sql = "select 
                 name, other, data 
              from 
                dbo.person p 
                inner join dbo.anothertable a on p.personid = a.personid"
```

EDIT:

After a bit of clarification, you want to set up [insert triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) on your tables to monitor them.  I'd suggest something like this:

1. An insert occurs, and the OnInsert trigger fires.
2. The insert trigger puts logging information into a logging table.
3. Your c# application polls that table for new information and executes accordingly.

Some ideas like this are discussed in [Some data changes in the database. How can I trigger some C# code doing some work upon these changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513940/some-data-changes-in-the-database-how-can-i-trigger-some-c-sharp-code-doing-som)

Comment: thanks paqogomez ___ you right __ but i want monitor table seperatly__  for example i want do action "A" when table person change And do action "B" when table2 change ___ Can i do it ?

Comment: @user1971217 I think you might be after 2 different ideas here.  Let me see if I understand.  First, if you want to know when something is inserted into your db, use an [OnInsert trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).  This is just sql however.  it does not send events to your c# program.  I think you would just have to poll a table.  [Check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513940/some-data-changes-in-the-database-how-can-i-trigger-some-c-sharp-code-doing-som)

Comment: thanks again paqogomez , i can create any trigger on any table , but i  dont know how get they when execute ___ trigger is best sulotion for me , but my problem is i dont know HOW DO ACTION IN C# AFTER ANY TRIGGER EXECUTE ___ Can You Help me ?

Comment: @user1971217 There is nothing that will SEND A SIGNAL to your c# app.  The best you can do is POLL (query on a loop) the database.  I explain this in the edit steps in my answer.