# What can I use instead of SQLCashDependency And AggregateCacheDependency in C# Windows Application?

Tags: c#, sql

after very reserach about monitor moluti tables for notification , i found only SQLDependency And AggregateCacheDependency For C# . 
But this Classes are in System.Web Namespace and not available from windwos application .

now i want anything that can Match some sqlDependency in my code .

i already [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048568/how-do-add-multi-sql-dependency-to-this-code) , but i want monitor multi tables

and if possible i want anyone explain cycle of sqldependency work in order 
for example like this :
1- create onchange method for check sql dependency
2- start sqldependency
3- , ...

plaese dont link to other pages , i tried for 7-8 days and can't find anything that useful for me

thanks a lot

Comment: Why not just have multiple SqlDependancy objects?

Comment: i know it , but how monitor those  SqlDependancy objects? Based on my research it is possible only with SqlCashDependency And AggregateCashDependency That are in system.web namespace , and in My windows application not available ...